# Sorting an array upon completion of Http post

Tags: httpclient

I want to post **several** requests asynchronously
with the following code:

```
this.http.post (TGT_IP,body,{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).subscribe 
    (
      (val) => 
      {
          console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
            }
          }
      },
      response => {
        console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
          **//TODO: sort the array** 
      });
```

In each request I'm sorting the array. It works.
Is it possible to wait till all requests are completed and then sort the array only once ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 1):

It should be just happenstance that `console.log` is fired only after all requests have returned (determined by the server's response time). What you're doing is generating several asynchronous promises and telling each one what to do when it completes. To make several http requests synchronously you might want to try something like:

```
let promises = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  promises.push(this.http.post(TGT_IP,body,{responseType:'arraybuffer'}).toPromise());
 }
console.log(Promise.all(promises));
```